# Excel vba, split worksheet at page break, save as pdf, and autoname based on value

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, save-as

I'm just starting to get to grips with some basic vba and have been using the code below to split a large sheet into seperate xls files where it finds a page break (which have been inserted using a subtotal function). This code also names each file based on the value in a cell.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rowCurrent As Long, rowPrevious As Long, i As Long
    Dim oWB As Workbook, newWbk As Workbook
    Dim oWS As Worksheet

    Set oWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Set oWS = oWB.Sheets("Specials")

    rowPrevious = oWS.UsedRange.Row + oWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

    For i = oWS.HPageBreaks.Count To 0 Step -1
        If i = 0 Then
            oWS.Rows("1:" & rowPrevious).Copy
        Else
            rowCurrent = oWS.HPageBreaks(i).Location.Row
            oWS.Rows(rowCurrent & ":" & rowPrevious).Copy
        End If

        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "c:\folder1\folder2" & ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value & -i
        ActiveWorkbook.Close

        rowPrevious = rowCurrent - 1
    Next
End Sub
```

I would like to perform the same operation as above but have a pdf outputted at the end instead of an xlsx file.

I've tried adding a ".pdf" into the *ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs* line but no luck.

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions, sure I'm missing something obvious.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recording a macro and hitting F12 (SaveAs) and saving as PDF produces this code:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "{path}\Book1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False
```

Don't use the `SaveAs` method, use `ExportAsFixedFormat` to save as PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Forgive the slightly dense question, but would I just need to paste the above after the Workbooks.Add line?